# SPD workflow - Stop workflow if item is deleted

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

Environment SharePoint 2010 standard

I have create a SharePoint designer workflow attached to a content type. The content type is then attached to a SharePoint list.

In the workflow I have set action "pause for a duration" and the workflow is triggers when item is changed. I have deleted the item before the workflow resumes from pause but the workflow still has reference to the deleted item and it continues to execute the remaining steps in the workflow.

How do I check if the item is deleted or stop the workflow when item is deleted?

Comment: I just found that the item ID changes to Zero for deleted items.